# How filter entity B in join jpa

Tags: jpa, jpql

- I have an `Entity_A` that has `OneToMany` relationship  with `Entity_B`.
- `Entity_B` has a flag which indicates whether it is active.

How can I select join entity A and only entity B if it is active?

Comment: Check out my answer update, hope that help you to fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

[JPA Query:Documention](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-implicit-join)

```
SELECT DISTINCT entA FROM Entity_A entA JOIN FETCH entA.entityBSet as entB WHERE entB.active = true
```

**Update**
- try [@where](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Where.html)

```
@Entity
public class Entity_A {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private Integer id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entityA")
  @Where("active = true")
  private Set<Entity_B> entityBSet;
}

@Entity
public class Entity_B {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private Integer id;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "ACTIVE")
  private Integer active;

  @ManyToOne
  private Entity_A entityA;
}
```